# Multiple Blogs on Husbspot

Tags: hubspot

Have 4 blogs in hubspot.
Say A B C D
On the backend: They are separated
On the Frontend: they are blog.url/a  /b /c etc
I would like to have a blog in a, also show up in b. 
I tired tags, but that just outputs them a topics.

Is there a way to have a post show up in two blogs other than duplicating?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to have two separate blogs show on the same listing without using the recent_topic_tag and using HubL and HTML.

What you can do is call all four blogs using topics and use HubL to remove those not that doesn't have that topic. Then just using the published date, you can sort them in a order using HubL.